# On increasing union of σ-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, examples-counterexamples

Let $U$  be uniformly distributed on the interval $ [0, 1] $. Consider the
decimal digits of $ U $, calling them $ Z_1, Z_2, Z_3, \ldots $
Consider $C =\bigcup σ(Z_1, Z_2, \ldots , Z_n) $. This is an increasing union of σ-algebras.
a) Is $C $ a σ-algebra?
b)$C$ is as large as $σ(U) $,

I am looking for some counterexample for part (a) and what are the examples of sets that are in $σ(U)$ but not in $C$ with valid convincing argument.

Comment: Consider $A=[Z_n=0\ \text{for infinitely many}\ n]$.

Comment: Could please explain me in a more details.

Comment: Sure, but you first: what can you say about A?